# How to fix "Error: NewController could not be found." error in CakePHP2

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Can't seem to overcome the problem where I HAVE to create a NewController even though I don't want that name for the controller.

I have configured the database and that's about it.

- database.php:
  class PostsController extends AppController {
      public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

  ```
  public function index() {
      $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
  }
  ```

  }

Hey, so I'm new to CakePHP and I'm using the 2nd version. I have configured the database.php file to my requirements but as soon as I open the website path, I get an error saying "Error: NewController could not be found.".
Also, "Error: Create the class NewController below in file: app\Controller\NewController.php"

I don't want to create a NewController rather I am creating a PostsController to display posts I have in my database.
Thank you!

Comment: Is this a brand new project? If so, you should really be using the latest version, not 2.x.

Comment: Yes, it is a brand new project but my boss wants me to use CakePHP 2. I'm a little confused as to why he wants that but I can't do anything about it.

Comment: You can point out that there is a much newer, highly recommended new version, and that starting a new project in a version that's less supported by third-party libraries will add time to your task, and using a version that's quite incompatible with the latest version is going to mean you'll run into end-of-life problems and have to re-implement things. Present a well reasoned argument and you may find that the requirement isn't as strong as you think it is; decisions are often made based on incomplete data, and could have been corrected if only someone had spoken up.

Comment: Hmm, you know what I will talk to my boss. I had the same opinion at the beginning but they didn't seem to like the sound of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. 
The problem was just that I had created nested directories within the 'www' folder where I was saving my project. 
All I had to do was place the project folder in the 'www' directory and it worked!
Thank you all. Have a great day :)